# Datatype in INNER select statement is defined as MONEY but then is changed in outer SELECT statement to int datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my t-sql code below, in the INNER SELECT I am doing a SUM(t.WrittenPremium) and the t.WrittenPremium is defined as a MONEY datatype  but then in the OUTER SELECT statement when I hover over the a.WrittenPremium it is NOW an INT datatype.  The reason for the question is that I'm getting an error in a SSRS report that I'm working on from the results of this query stating that the WrittenPremium cannot be converted to String though I'm not trying to convert anything to a string.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.[Period] = '' THEN a.[Year] + ' - Total '+a.TermType
        ELSE a.[Year] 
    END as [Year]
    , a.[Period]
    , a.TermType
    , a.WrittenPremium
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN GROUPING (t.[Year]) = 1 THEN 'Total'
            ELSE t.[Year]
        END as [Year]
        , ISNULL(t.[Period],'') as [Period]
        , ISNULL(t.TermType,'') as TermType
        , SUM(t.WrittenPremium) as WrittenPremium
        , RN
    FROM #temp t 
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((t.[Year], t.[Period], t.TermType, t.RN), (t.[Year], t.TermType))
) a
ORDER BY 1 asc, a.RN asc, a.TermType;
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the assuption that Year is an INT datatype I think the type mismatch is happen in the CASE setting Year. Please try this:

```
        CASE 
            WHEN GROUPING (t.[Year]) = 1 THEN 'Total'
            ELSE CAST(t.[Year] AS VARCHAR(10))
        END as [Year]
```

Comment: thanks for responding, the Year datatype was an int and I tried what you suggested and the t.WrittenPremium datatype is still returning an INT datatype.  Seems weird to me.  I then did a CAST on the YEAR data type earlier in my code from the source where I got the YEAR value and that still did not work.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the base data, not really. SSRS may convert datatype money to string on its own. My first appraoch would be to change WrittenPremium into DECIMAL or even INTEGER in #temp-table to rule out this behaviour.